# .html() not working for live update of html table after jquery $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a jQuery dialogue box ( http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/ ) which when the user clicks on a table  with class low_inv_notes, will pop up and allow them to enter in whatever notes they want.

The note gets properly stored in the database, however I am trying to achieve a live update of the table td when they hit submit on that dialogue box, and this is not working. If the user wants to see the updated table they must reload the page which is not something i want.

I believe my problem has something to do with .html(); I have made alerts to check the variables i am using have values and i have checked to make sure all id's and class's are properly labels.

Here is the code for my dialogue box at the moment:

```
 $( ".low_inv_notes" ).click(function(event) {

var notes = $(this).andSelf().html();
var netQty = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(6)').text();
var stockNumber = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();


    var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
        .html('<textarea id="noteContent" style="width: 450px; height: 190px;">' + notes + '</textarea>')
        .dialog({ title: 'Edit This Note:',
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 300,
                    width: 500,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                      "Submit":function() {

                             var old = notes;
                             var new_notes =  $("#noteContent").val();

                            if(new_notes == old){
                                 alert("Note is the same - change to submit"); 

                                 $(this).dialog('close');
                                 $(this).dialog('open');

                             }
                             else {

                                     $.post( "edit_low_inv_notes.php", { netQty:netQty, stockNumber: stockNumber, new_notes: new_notes},function(data){

                                            var id = stockNumber+'notes';
                                            //alert(id);
                                            //alert(new_notes);
                                            //$('#00260040.01Dnotes').html('test');
                                            $('#'+id).html(new_notes);
                                            }
                                    );



                            $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();
                             }

                      },

                      "Close":function() {  
                            $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();
                      } 
                    }
                });

  $dialog.dialog( "open" );
 });
```

I have tried substituting .text in for .html as well as having .done before the function(data) with the same amount of success. any ideas? Thanks ahead of time

Comment: You're positive `stockNumber+'notes'` is the ID of the HTML element? Try and use `console.log(id)` and `console.log(new_notes)` to verify you're attempting to put the right content into the right element that you're expecting.

Comment: @kinakuta I think that the code is making the assumption that the "new notes", being what was sent back to the server, are the appropriate new contents for the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the problem is with the `.` character in the middle of your element id. If your id value really looks like "00260040.01D", then jQuery is going to interpret that `.` as being a class selector.

You can try this:

```
$('#' + id.replace(/\./g, '\\.')).html(new_notes);
```

Comment: yep this works fantastic, the . was throwing off the .html, such a quick response, much appreciated. Thanks!